Why does the edit mode no longer remember the shading mode?
About a year ago, I was able to have edit mode remember that it should be in wireframe mode. That is, I could do something in edit mode, then switch to object mode using the tab key (and the display mode would automatically switch to solid), and then switch back to edit mode, and the display mode would switch back to wireframe.
Now a few more Blender versions have come to pass, and despite searching the settings, I've been unable to restore this behaviour. I have also looked briefly into answers to similar questions, but before I immerse myself into the inner workings of custom shortcuts, I'd like to ask where the relevant setting is; it should exist, because it is hard to believe that the Blender developers have simply let this feature disappear.
Thank you very much in advance.

it still works this way, if you have chosen the Wireframe display mode and switch from Edit to Object and then back to Edit it keeps the Wireframe display mode...

Yes, but it also keeps the wireframe mode in Object mode. That's the problem.

oh ok, i'm not used to the wireframe mode
